# What does the objective "kill 4 nones" mean?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Just got an objective to kill 4 nones without weapons, am I missing something or is this a glitch?[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot ? Feels like a glitch to me.

Comment: Could we get a screenshot?

Comment: Sounds like a placeholder value for an object that doesnt have a name property or something

Comment: [There's a kill 2 deathclaw without a weapon objective](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3gy8j0/kill_2_deathclaws_without_a_weapon/) so I suspect this is just a forgotten change to the objective description but it probably will work.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible that this is some sort of glitch, more specifically a null pointer error, as there is no such entity named "None" in Fallout Shelter or the Fallout universe in general.

In many languages a mistake could be made in the code which causes an 'object', such as the name of an enemy you need to kill, to end up being nothing or `null`.

Some languages such as Python and possibly others use the notation `None` instead of `null`.

Likely there is also code that attempts to make the object plural if you have to kill more than one so `None` gets an `s` appended to the end.

This is possibly why you are getting that being displayed.

It's possible that this is still achievable, but it is unlikely and I'd recommend skipping it.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are particularly keen on testing, I'd suggest skipping that Objective. There is a very high chance it is something that didn't get added or is intended for a future update. As such there is probably very little chance of accomplishing it unless it turns out that "Nones" was supposed to be Molerats or Deathclaws and just didn't get changed when they were added. I doubt that this is accomplishable.

Comment: Molerats/deathclaws have been added to the game, and I believe from looking at the code, that they reference properly. None seems to be a null reference.

Comment: Last night before I went to bed I got **Kill 4 Deathclaws without a weapon**; this morning when I loaded the game, it had changed to **Kill 4 Nones without a weapon**: I would guess that it is somehow related to your chance of a Deathclaw attack, and in my case it went from a small chance to <0 chance and so threw an exception (as it were).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same thing happen to me. Originally the objective said kill 1 'raider' without a weapon, logged out of the game and back in later and noticed it said 'none' instead of raider. Worth noting that once the text/objective bugged I wasn't able to complete the objective despite several tries and had to dismiss it.